# Installing System Font with Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, truetype

I have a folder filled with TTF files of custom fonts.  I need to install them as system fonts using a powershell script (this is on Windows Server 2008 R2).  Does anybody know how to do that in powershell?
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is quite simple. Take a look on the snippet below:

```
$FONTS = 0x14
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($FONTS)
$objFolder.CopyHere("C:\test\Myfont.ttf")
```

And it should not require to restart/logoff...

The 0x14 value is the CLSID of the special folder.

In addition I just found this tutorial explaining each step above:

http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/trick-installing-fonts-vbscript-or-powershell-script

Comment: Thanks!  I'll test it out.  What does the 0x14 signify?  Is that the value of the fonts namespace?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code with the answer and a link, please check it out.

Comment: This will popup a confirmation dialog box in the case where a font is already installed - not ideal for scripting mass installation of fonts.

Comment: This shows dialog which can't be hidden, and it also installs as the user (appdata), not as system windows\fonts

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to post an alternative which doesn't require `0x14` to be hard coded into the script. Pass the file object to the function, and it will just run the "Install" based on where the file is:

```
Function Install-Font {
   Param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][System.IO.FileSystemInfo[]]$File
   )
   $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
   $File | % {
      $Fonts = $shell.NameSpace($_.Directory.Name)
      $font = $Fonts.ParseName($_.Name)
      $font.InvokeVerb("Install")
   }
}
```

Comment: `$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application` doesn't work with me, only in interactive mode. Any prerequisite?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Shell.Application` COM object doesn't work on Server Core (at least not on 2012 R2).

I had success by simply copying the font file to `C:\Windows\Fonts` (in this case times.ttf) and then adding the corresponding registry entry with PowerShell:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts' -Name 'Times New Roman (TrueType)' -PropertyType String -Value times.ttf
```

Removal is the reverse of installation. The only downside is that a restart is required both after the font has been installed and also before it is uninstalled if an application has referenced it.

Answer (score 0):

Shell code has been known to fail on Remote and Build agents - if the comobjects using shell are failing and you are vetting via Remote or Build agents then you will need to use the framework classes to do this ([reference](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/05/27/avoid-using-shell-command-in-powershell-scipts/))

```
## Add or Remove Font Files - only tested with TTF font files thus far
#<#
#=======================================================================================================
# ADD or REMOVE MULTIPLE FONT FILES [Using ComObjects]
#=======================================================================================================
# This code will install or uninstall a font using ComObject
# You Must Modify the following variables in order to work
# (A) $dirFiles                ==>  This is the source folder path that contains all of your font files
# (B) $InstallOrUninstall      ==>  $true = Install Font ...  $false = UnInstall Font
#=======================================================================================================
    # Define Working Variables
        $dirFiles = "C:\Temp\Fonts"
        $InstallOrUninstall = $false  # $true = Install = 1  ...or...  $false = UnInstall = 0
        $srcFontFiles = Get-ChildItem "$($dirFiles)\Fonts"
        $Fonts = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace(0x14)
    # Copy each file into the Font Folder or Delete it - Depends on the $InstallOrUninstall variable setting
        ForEach($srcFontFile in $srcFontFiles) 
        {
            $srcFontFileName = $srcFontFile.name
            $srcFontFileFullPath = $srcFontFile.fullname
            $targFonts = "C:\Windows\Fonts\$($srcFontFileName)"
            If (Test-Path $targFonts -PathType any) { Remove-Item $targFonts -Recurse -Force } # UnInstall Font
            If ((-not(Test-Path $targFonts -PathType container)) -and ($InstallOrUninstall -eq $true)) { $fonts.CopyHere($srcFontFileFullPath, 16) } # Install Font
        }
#>
```

Comment: Shell code has been known to fail on Remote and Build agents - if the comobjects using shell are failing and you are vetting via Remote or Build agents then you will need to use the framework classes to do this - ref : http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/05/27/avoid-using-shell-command-in-powershell-scipts/

Comment: please add some explanation

Comment: see the link i provided in my last comment - it has everything you need to know