# Fonts are not registering using powershell script

Tags: powershell, fonts, registry

i have made this script to copy fonts from a server to the a temp folder on the computer and then install it but it copys and does all that but doesnt register the fonts in the registry.

```
#map network drive
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("Y:", "\\address\c$", $false, "\username", "password")

#take away system attribute on font folder 
attrib -r -s "C:\Windows\Fonts"

#specify path location
$NetworkPath = "Y:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\fontsFolder\"
$LocalPath= "C:\FontsTesting\"

$objShell = new-object -comobject shell.application
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace(0x14)

#Take a copy of the font folder from the server
 New-Item $LocalPath -type directory -Force
Copy-Item "$NetworkPath\*" $LocalPath

#Copy the directory of the local path to a temp value        
$Fontdir = dir $LocalPath

         foreach($File in $Fontdir) 
        {
          if ((Test-Path "C:\Windows\Fonts\$File") -eq $False)
            {
                $objFolderItem = $objFolder.ParseName($fontName)
                    if (!$objFolderItem)
                           {
                             $objFolder.CopyHere($File.fullname)
                           }
            }
        }


#add attributes back and delete mapped drive and remove temp font folder
remove-item $LocalPath -recurse -Force
attrib +r +s "C:\Windows\Fonts"
net use /delete Y:
```

the fonts are all different types and all the different types dont register.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: interesting reading: http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2010/12/04/adding-and-removing-fonts-with-windows-powershell.aspx and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16023285/520612

Comment: The problem is my fonts are not registering using this script. It copies to the font folder but doesnt register. I tried adding a script to add the registry key in one by one but i cant get the actual font name from the font file. For example the font itself is times new roman but can have a file name anfoergn.otf ... so i need to extract the actual name to add it to the registry.